# Vimeo API OAuth 2.0 for iOS - Authentication token not received

Tags: ios, oauth, vimeo-api

I was trying to authenticate App to access Vimeo using their API. I don't seem to get through this. I can see the page where vimeo request for access from the user and on clicking the 'Allow' button it displays an error. I'm using [GTM-OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/source/checkout)

I have added the code below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self signInToVimeo];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#define ClientID    @"clientID"
#define ClientSecret @"clientSecret"
#define AuthURL   @"https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize"
#define TokenURL  @"https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/request_token"


- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * )authForVimeo
{
 //This URL is defined by the individual 3rd party APIs, be sure to read their documentation

  NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:TokenURL];
// We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
// the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
// loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page. This needs to match the URI set as the
// redirect URI when configuring the app with Instagram.
  NSString * redirectURI = @"Simple-OAuth2://";
  GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

  auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"Vimeo"
                                                         tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:ClientID
                                                     clientSecret:ClientSecret];
  auth.scope = @"public";
  return auth;
}


 - (void)signInToVimeo{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self authForVimeo];

    // Display the authentication view
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                            authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AuthURL]
                                                                                            keychainItemName:@"VimeoKeychainItem"
                                                                                                    delegate:self
                                                                                            finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
  }


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
             error:(NSError * )error
{
  NSLog(@"finished");
  NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);

   [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:NO];
     if (error != nil) {
      UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Vimeo"
                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
    } else {

      UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Vimeo"
                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
 }
}

 @end
```

I don't receive the authentication token. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciedy5r2zmu7ddx/photo.PNG?m=) is a screenshot on clicking the 'Allow' button.

Answer (score 0):

Your client ID and client secret should be ones you obtain from Vimeo developer website not "clientID"/"clientSecret".

Comment: Did you think he'd put his real client_id and client_secret in his post on here ?